# Как получить таймер запущенного приложения

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что мне нужно получить таймера в диспетчере приложений. У меня 2 приложения и мне нужно получить время обеих в списке выполняемых приложений. 
Я представления даже не имею, куда нужно копать, как их получить?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы по этой ссылке, возможно это то, что вам нужно http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/how-can-i-start-android-application-info-screen-programmatically